# How to avoid repeated data in a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

What's the best way to create a query that returns a dynamic result, in my postgresql i have three tables:

```
contacts |contact_emails| contact_numbers
id       | id           | id
descrip  | id_contact   | id_contact
name     | email        | number
```

and i want to create a result something like:

```
contact_name| contact_emailx| contact_numbersx
```

Those "x" are the emails and the numbers that can have a contact

I was trying using left join, this is my code:

```
SELECT c.id, c.contact_name, cn.number, ce.email 
FROM contacts c 
LEFT JOIN contact_numbers cn ON c.id = cn.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN contact_emails ce ON c.id = ce.contact_id 
WHERE c.user_id = 1
```

But it returns [image]

I expect something like:

```
 contact_name |number1  | number2  |email
LA MEJOR      | 25445877| 25845877 |AMEJOR@GMAIL.COM
```

or

```
 contact_name    |number1  | number2  |email1          | email2
EDIFICADORA JUANA| 24602254| 55655545 |oipoa@gmaio.com |rst008@guan.com
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What's your question?  You have referenced `contact_desc` (column `descrip`?) in your specifications and not included it in your SQL, but otherwise how does your output differ from what you want?

Comment: The diference is that i need for example in the image only "LA MEJOR" with the numbers and the email,no two times, for example i expect something like: 

"LA MEJOR", 25445877, 25845877, "AMEJOR@GMAIL.COM" @rd_nielsen

Comment: Just  [`SELECT DISTINCT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) (or `GROUP BY`)

Comment: As @joanolo says, you can eliminate the duplicates in your query, but you're getting the duplicates because there are duplicate rows for the same contact ID in at least one of your tables, not because of the multiple left joins.

Comment: @rd_nielsen: I guess each *contact* can have several phones and several emails...

Comment: Yes, thats my problem, i dont know if with joins it's correct @joanolo

Comment: Your joins are correct (although probably not optimal), but you need to *aggregate* the results (`GROUP BY`). See answer.

Comment: BTW: I'd change the title of your post to something like "How to avoid repeated data in a query?", or something like this. Your query isn't actually a [*dynamic query*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to aggregate all your emails and all your numbers into two *arrays*:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.contact_name, array_agg(DISTINCT cn.number) AS numbers, array_agg(DISTINCT ce.email) AS emails
FROM 
    contacts c 
    LEFT JOIN contact_numbers cn ON c.id = cn.contact_id 
    LEFT JOIN contact_emails ce  ON c.id = ce.contact_id 
WHERE 
    c.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    c.id
ORDER BY
    c.id ;
```

```
id | contact_name      | numbers             | emails                             
-: | :---------------- | :------------------ | :----------------------------------
 2 | LA MEJOR          | {25445877}          | {AHEJOR@GMAIL.COM,AMEJOR@GMAIL.COM}
 3 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | {24602254}          | {oipoa@gmaio.com,rst008@guan.com}  
 4 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | {24602254,55655545} | {oipoa@gmaio.com,rst008@guan.com}  
 5 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | {24602254,55655545} | {oipoa@gmaio.com,rst008@guan.com}
```

As an alternative, you can subqueries (which might be faster under some circumstances):

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.contact_name, 
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT cn.number) FROM contact_numbers cn WHERE cn.contact_id = c.id) AS numbers, 
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT ce.email)  FROM contact_emails  ce WHERE ce.contact_id = c.id) AS emails
FROM 
    contacts c 
WHERE 
    c.user_id = 1 
ORDER BY
    c.id ;
```

```
id | contact_name      | numbers             | emails                             
-: | :---------------- | :------------------ | :----------------------------------
 2 | LA MEJOR          | {25445877}          | {AHEJOR@GMAIL.COM,AMEJOR@GMAIL.COM}
 3 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | {24602254}          | {oipoa@gmaio.com,rst008@guan.com}  
 4 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | {24602254,55655545} | {oipoa@gmaio.com,rst008@guan.com}  
 5 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | {24602254,55655545} | {oipoa@gmaio.com,rst008@guan.com}
```

If you want to *separate* the (first) two emails and numbers, you can do it by wrapping up the previous query:

```
SELECT
    id, contact_name, 
    numbers[1] AS number1,
    numbers[2] AS number2,
    emails[1]  AS email1,
    emails[2]  AS email2
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        c.id, c.contact_name, 
        (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT cn.number) FROM contact_numbers cn WHERE cn.contact_id = c.id) AS numbers, 
        (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT ce.email)  FROM contact_emails  ce WHERE ce.contact_id = c.id) AS emails
    FROM 
        contacts c 
    WHERE 
        c.user_id = 1 
) AS q
ORDER BY
    id ;
```

```
id | contact_name      |  number1 |  number2 | email1           | email2          
-: | :---------------- | -------: | -------: | :--------------- | :---------------
 2 | LA MEJOR          | 25445877 |     null | AHEJOR@GMAIL.COM | AMEJOR@GMAIL.COM
 3 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | 24602254 |     null | oipoa@gmaio.com  | rst008@guan.com 
 4 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | 24602254 | 55655545 | oipoa@gmaio.com  | rst008@guan.com 
 5 | EDIFICADORA JUANA | 24602254 | 55655545 | oipoa@gmaio.com  | rst008@guan.com
```

You can check everything online at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ccac2dc617d8b675a7111c00d6464494)*

---

Tables and data used:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL /* REFERENCES users(id) */,
    descrip text,
    contact_name character varying(255)
) ;

CREATE TABLE contact_emails
(
    contact_id  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES contacts(id),
    email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(contact_id, email)   -- This is the natural key for this table, no need for synthetic id
) ;

CREATE TABLE contact_numbers
(
    contact_id  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES contacts(id),
    number integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(contact_id, number)   -- Again...
) ;
```

... and data

```
INSERT INTO 
    contacts
    (id, user_id, descrip, contact_name)
VALUES
    (2, 1, '', 'LA MEJOR'),
    (3, 1, '', 'EDIFICADORA JUANA'),
    (4, 1, '', 'EDIFICADORA JUANA'),
    (5, 1, '', 'EDIFICADORA JUANA') ;

INSERT INTO
    contact_emails
    (contact_id, email)
VALUES
    (2, 'AMEJOR@GMAIL.COM'),
    (2, 'AHEJOR@GMAIL.COM'),
    (3, 'oipoa@gmaio.com'),
    (3, 'rst008@guan.com'),
    (4, 'oipoa@gmaio.com'),
    (4, 'rst008@guan.com'),
    (5, 'oipoa@gmaio.com'),
    (5, 'rst008@guan.com') ;

INSERT INTO
    contact_numbers
    (contact_id, number)
VALUES
    (2, '25445877'),
    (3, '24602254'),
    (4, '24602254'),
    (4, '55655545'),
    (5, '24602254'),
    (5, '55655545') ;
```

NOTE: There are lots of repeated values, infered from the data on your image.

Comment: Thanks a lot @joanolo, a questionm with the array_args can i group more emails and numbers, more than two?

Comment: Yes, as many as necessary (then, you'll to compute email3, email4, ... as needed, if you want to do the equivalent of an "unpivot").

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot again!